# Range.cloneRange() does not actually clone the range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I'm trying to reset the cursor position after changing the html in a `contenteditable` `span`. To do this, I clone the current range, then set the html, then clear the ranges, then add the range and finally collapse. But when I change the html, the cloned range is reset! This leads me to believe that the cloned range is not actually a deep copy, because otherwise, why would changing the html affect it? I think that I can copy all the attributes manually, but that sounds painful. Anyway, what's the proper way to copy a range?

```js
$("#myText").on("input", function() {
  var temp = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
  console.log(temp);
  $("#myText").html($("#myText").html());
  //clear current range
  console.log(temp);
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  //add the range
  window.getSelection().addRange(temp);
  //now move the carret to there
  window.getSelection().collapseToEnd();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myText" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">Hello!</span>
```

(or on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jm4bdqzp/1/))

Comment: Please always try to add a [mcve] in the question itself (preferable as snippet -> `<>` / Ctrl+M) and not only a link to an external resource that may be not available (offline, blocked, ...). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/).

Comment: Did you find any answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

When you execute this line:

```
$("#myText").html($("#myText").html());
```

You trigger the page to parse that input and create new children nodes. When you clone a range it still points to the old nodes, which get removed, thus both original and cloned ranges reset